# Restrict azure app service Custom domain access to specific tenant

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service, vpn, multi-tenant, custom-domain

I am developing multitenant web application which is being hosted on azure app service.
It has 2 parts one is backend services which has pure APIs developed using .NET CORE and second is front end which consumes these APIs and is developed using Angular.

We are using Single instance , database per tenant concept where each user will have its own Database.
So there will be a catalog Db , which will hold information about each customer's tenant Id, tenant's Database connection string , customer Id etc.

We do not want to use Azure AD as of now, as our APIs are connecting to different ERPs to validate the user and data.

To achieve multitenancy, we are thinking of 2 ways

1. Unique Secret Id called TenantKey (for which we will be using some hashing function on TenanatId)

   So every time they login, they need to enter this TenantKey along with UserId and password , so we authenticate this user based on that TenantKey and fetch DB connection string based on this.
   We validate user by connecting to their own DB using Connection string fetched from CatalogDb.
   Once we validate, we generate JWT token and this Connection string of Tenant's own Db is stored as Claim and will be used every time when user calls any API using this token.

This is working fine but

- user has to remember and enter this TenanatKey along with UserId and password when they login everytime... which may not be user friendly...
- As it is multitenant app, If another tenant gets to know the TenantKey they can access the info provided that they know the credentials(rare but possible)

2. Custom Domains

As Azure provides way to add custom domains to Azure App service through which we can identify the Tenant and Instead of TenatKey, we will be using this custom domain to find the Connection string  in Catalog Db, create JWT token and store as Claim and use it

So question is , is there any way to secure these custom domains so only particular customer can access it? Like in their VPN?
I heard there is limit of 500 domains that can be added to an App service? will there be any way to extend if needed?
We will have load balancer going forward, will this customer domain have any effect on that?

Answer (score 0):

**Restrict your multi-tenant app to specific tenant**

There are two steps to get started with tenant restrictions.

- First, make sure that your clients can connect to the right
  addresses.
- Second, configure your proxy infrastructure.

To use tenant restrictions, your clients must be able to connect to the following Azure AD URLs to authenticate: [login.microsoftonline.com](https://login.microsoftonline.com/), [login.microsoft.com](https://login.microsoft.com/), and [login.windows.net](https://login.windows.net/). Additionally, to access Office 365, your clients must also be able to connect to the fully qualified domain names (FQDNs), URLs, and IP addresses defined in [Office 365 URLs and IP address ranges](https://support.office.com/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2)

For information on how to configure the proxy and the above process, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions).

Output will be like this after configuring:
[image]

---

**Restrict your multi-tenant app to specific users**

If an app is secured with Azure AD, it's available to all users who authenticate successfully. But we will have the requirements to restrict access to specific users. This can traditionally be done within the application based on the roles.

Tenant admins and developers can restrict an app to a specific set of users or security groups in the tenant by also using this built-in Azure AD functionality.

**Step 1**

Log in to the [Azure](https://portal.azure.com/) portal as a Global Administrator. In the top Azure bar search for the “Azure Active Directory”.
[image]

**Step 2**
From the properties left pane look for the “Enterprise applications” like below,
[image]

**Step 3**

Look for the AD application which you want, if you don’t find your application then select “All Applications” from the Application Type dropdown and use other filters also to find the application.
[image]

**Step 4**

Once you select the application, select “Properties” in the left menu and enable the “User assignment required” option to “Yes” and “Save” to update this configuration change.
[image]

**Step 5**

Make user assignments: Select “Users and groups” > Click “Add user”.
[image]

**Step 6**

It will direct you to the next page, where you may choose which users have access to the app services made available through this particular Azure AD app authentication.

[image]

Now, the user will be successfully authenticated when they attempt to log in to your Azure App Service with any legitimate AD user, but they will only be able to approve the application based on the configurations we just made.

For more information, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) in Microsoft documentations.

---

> I heard there is limit of 500 domains that can be added to an App service? will there be any way to extend if needed?

Yes, What you heard is correct!
[image]

You could try to contact Azure support to increase the limit:

- Navigate to your subscription in the Azure Portal
- Click on  `Usage + Quota`
- Click on  `Request increase`
- Select  `Other Request`  in the  `Quota Type`  field
- Fill all other fields of the request